# Logback logstash basic authentication in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, logstash, logback

I have logstash running with the following input configuration.

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5044
    codec => json_lines
    user => myuser
    password => "$tr0ngP4ssWD!"
  }
}
```

And I have a Spring boot service that wants to send logs to the above logstash server. Spring boot app used net.logstash.logback library for logging, and sending over the logs to logstash. Here's the logback configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <appender name="stash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>xx.x.xx.xxx:5044</destination>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <mdc/> <!-- MDC variables on the Thread will be written as JSON fields-->
                <context/> <!--Outputs entries from logback's context -->
                <version/> <!-- Logstash json format version, the @version field in the output-->
                <logLevel/>
                <loggerName/>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {


   <!-- we can add some custom fields to be sent with all the log entries.-->
                    <!--make filtering easier in Logstash-->
                    "appName": "elk-demo",
                    "appVersion": "1.0"
                    }
                </pattern>
            </pattern>
            <!--<threadName/>-->
            <message/>
            <logstashMarkers/> <!-- Useful so we can add extra information for specific log lines as Markers-->
            <arguments/> <!--or through StructuredArguments-->
            <stackTrace/>
        </providers>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>

<logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
```

Problem is that I am not sure where to put the the logstash credentials (user and password) in the logback configuration file. There's nothing in the net.logstash.logback documentation about security.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a concrete answer that I know works, but the information I can imagine you're looking for is under the SSH-section [here](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#ssl). The `net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender` might simply not support basic authentication. It's possible that you'd have to write your own if appender if that's the case.